# Perfect matchings, blossoms, and biconnected edges: need help understanding a claim

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading an early paper by Deming on Koenig graphs [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7pEy.png), and I am stuck trying to understand a claim in the paper.

#### Preliminaries

Let $G$ be a (finite, undirected, simple) graph. Fix a maximum matching $M$ of $G$. The edges in $M$ are said to be *heavy*; those not in $M$ are said to be *light*. A vertex $v$ of $G$ is said to be *exposed* relative to $M$ if $v$ is not the endpoint of any heavy edge of $G$. An *alternating path* from vertex $u$ to vertex $v$ is a path $p(u,v)$ whose edges are alternately light and heavy; such a path may begin or end with either a light edge or a heavy edge.

An odd cycle $v_{0},v_{1},\dotsc,v_{2k},v_{0}\;;\;k\geq1$ is called a *blossom* if edges $v_{1}v_{2},v_{3}v_{4},\dotsc,v_{2k-1}v_{2k}$ are heavy. The vertex $v_{0}$ in such a blossom is called the *blossom tip*.

Suppose there is an alternating path $v_{1},v_{2},\dotsc,v_{2k}\;;\;k\geq1$ in $G$ where the edges $v_{1}v_{2}$ and $v_{2k-1}v_{2k}$ are heavy and the vertices $v_{1}$ and $v_{2k}$ are blossom tips. "A configuration of this type" is called a *blossom pair* of $G$.

(I add the quotes because it is not clear to me what the author means by a configuration of this type: Does he mean just the path $v_{1},v_{2},\dotsc,v_{2k}$, or does he also mean to include the blossoms whose tips are $v_{1}$ and $v_{2k}$?)

#### The claim

Let $G$ be a graph with a perfect matching $M$, and $x_{1}x_{2}$ and $y_{1}y_{2}$ be heavy edges which belong to a blossom pair $B$ with respect to the matching $M$. Then for each $i,j=1,2$, there is an alternating path $p(x_{i},y_{j})$ beginning and ending with light edges and contained in $B$.

#### My question

Consider the graph below. It satisfies the conditions of the claim: It has a perfect matching (indicated by the "heavy" edges) and contains/is a blossom pair (depending on how we interpret the definition of a blossom pair above) with respect to this matching. Now $x_{1}x_{2}$ and $y_{1}y_{2}$ are heavy edges which belong to the blossom pair (for either interpretation), but there is no alternating path $p(x_{1},y_{2})$ which begins and ends with light edges. What gives?

[image: The example graph on eight vertices with a perfect matching. Two triangles joined by a path of length four connecting their "apices". The triangle edges which do not see the apices are both part of a matching of size four of this graph.]

Deming quotes Edmonds' *Paths, trees, and flowers* paper for terminology up to and including *blossom tip*. Just to be sure, I checked this latter paper: Edmonds uses "path" to mean "simple path", so it cannot be that Deming means "alternating walk" here when he says "alternating path".

What am I missing here?

#### Additional information

(May be of help in resolving my question.)

Deming goes on to define a pair of heavy edges $x_{1}x_{2}$ and $y_{1}y_{2}$ to be *biconnected* if there are alternating paths $p(x_{i},y_{j})$ for $i=1,2\;;\;j=1,2$ which begin and end with light edges. Then he states that any pair of biconnected heavy edges is contained in a blossom pair of the graph.

#### Picture mentioned in the comment to SE318's answer

[image: Similar to the picture above, with one triangle replaced by a pentagon.]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7pEy.png) Independence Numbers of Graphs -- An Extension of the Koenig-Egervary Theorem. Robert W. Deming, Discrete Mathematics 27 (1979) 23-33. [PDF](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X79900669#)

Comment: As a general suggestion: anything to do with matching in general (not bipartite) graphs tends to be a painful reading. So try to find secondary sources. Although matching in general graphs is covered well enough in some books, the Deming paper you mention is a bit obscure. I've only found it cited in Schrijver's magnum opus, section 30.15 together with Sterboul's result about the same topic. And Schrijver uses mostly Sterboul's presentation...

Comment: By the way, the claim is on p. 26 of the paper.

Comment: ... which is also page 4 of the paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of "blossom pair" Sterboul defined an "$M$-posy". Here's the passage from Schrijver:

[image]

> To characterize graphs $G$ with $ν(G) = τ (G)$, Sterboul defined, for any
>   graph $G = (V,E)$ and any matching $M$ in $G$, an $M$-posy to be an even-length
>   $M$-alternating closed walk $(v_0, v_1, . . . , v_t)$, with $v_{i−1}v_i ∈ M$ if $i$ is
>   even, such that there exist $i < j$ with $i$ odd and $j$ even, $v_1, . . . , v_j$ all distinct, $v_{j+1}, . . . , v_t$ all distinct, and
>
> (30.54) $v_i = v_t,$ $v_{i+1} = v_{t−1}, . . . , v_j = v_{t+i−j}$ .
>
> Lemma 30.13α. If there exists an even-length $M$-alternating closed walk
>   $C = (v_0, v_1, . . . , v_t)$ with $v_i = v_j$ for $i, j$ of different parity, then there exists an $M$-posy.

Both things you have drawn are $M$-posys. As you can see it's rather hairy to write down a formal definition fully capturing the picture.

---

EDIT: While I still haven't figured out what exactly Deming means by "biconnected" edges, his ultimate result in that section, his theorem 2, sheds some light on what he's trying to say:

> Theorem 2. An arbitrary graph G is K-E iff for any maximum matching M, the extension G’ contains no pair of biconnected heavy edges.

His definition of extension graph is straight-forward (and illustrated with examples so there's little doubt what it means):

> To construct $G’$, let $X$ be the set of exposed vertices of $G$ relative to a maximum
>   matching $M$. For each $x \in X$, add a new vertex $x’$ and new edges $xx’$ and $\{x’y : y \text{ is adjacent to } x\}$. $M’ = M \cup \{xx’ : x \in X\}$ is a perfect matching for $G’$.

(Exposed vertex means not included in the match.)

It helps to compare Deming's theorem 2 with its equivalent theorem 30.13 in Schrijver (which I'm abbreviating slightly):

> G has the Koenig property iff for each maximum-size matching M there is no M-flower and no M-posy

where M-flower is defined as the one-sided version of the M-posy:

[image]

If you take an M-flower and apply Deming's extension construction to it, you get an M-posy; only $v_0$ gets duplicated to a $v_0'$. So you can also phrase the theorem as: G has the Koenig property iff for each maximum-size matching of G' (denoted by M') there is no M'-posy. In other words, the forboding/constraint about M-flowers and M-posys in the original graph can be expressed just a constraint about  M-posys in Deming's extenstion graph. So by his "no pair of biconnected heavy edges" in G' he most likely means there's no M'-posy in G'. It's still not clear to me what exactly Deming means by "biconnected heavy edges" etc.

---

EDIT2: Actually, I understand now what Deming means by "biconnected heavy edges": there must be *four paths* beginning and ending with light edges: $x_1y_1$, $x_1y_2$, $x_2y_1$ and $x_2y_2$ must all be paths with this property (but the four paths need not be entirely distinct from each other). This def/interpretation is actually equivalent to the two heavy edges belonging to the opposite blossom ends of an M-possy. With this interpretation the "biconnected heavy edges" can't be in the same blossom (you'd have two light edges in a row by following the blossom cycle; and if you go around the other blossom it's not a simple path anymore), nor can they be in the "bridge" between the blossoms (you won't have four simple paths either then). So in the two graphs/matchings you've drawn, the highlighted $x_1x_2$ and $y_1y_2$ do not actually meet Deming's def of "biconnected heavy edges".

And getting back to "the claim", since it was intended to be half of this equivalence between "biconnected heavy edges" and M-posy, it should have been stated [by Deming] as: Let $G$ be a graph with a perfect matching $M$, and $x_{1}x_{2}$ and $y_{1}y_{2}$ be heavy edges *each belonging to an opposite blossom* of a blossom pair $B$ with respect to the matching $M$. Then for each $i,j=1,2$, there is an alternating path $p(x_{i},y_{j})$ beginning and ending with light edges and contained in $B$.

---

Note however that the equivalence between M-posy and biconnected heavy edges is wrong, because it fails in the other direction; after "the claim" [which at least could be patched] the paper says "A straightforward argument shows that a pair of biconnected heavy edges $x_1x_2$ and $y_1y_2$, are contained in a blossom pair B." [Kundor shows](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1178396/173347) that you can have biconnected heavy edges but one (or both) of the pair need not belong to an M-posy; this is because one (or both) of the biconnected heavy edges can belong to an even-length cycle in the matching and this cycle can share a heavy edge with an odd-length cycle (i.e. actual blossom belonging to an M-posy) which in turn can share another heavy edge with another even-length cycle. So you get some "extra" pairs of biconnected heavy edges not beloning to the actual M-posy but whose alternating, four go-between paths "pass through" the M-posy. (Without the M-posy facilitating this "crossover" you wouldn't get the 4 paths though.) Here's somewhat crude picture of Kundor's idea in a more general setting:

[image]

Deming's Theorem 2 still is correct though, but because the existence of a pair of biconnected heavy edges implies the existence of at least one M-posy (in the matching), even though not all biconnected heavy edges need belong to an M-posy. Proof that the existence of a pair of biconnected heavy edges implies the existence of an M-posy is not quite that trivial/obvious though.

Comment: Thank you, but this was not my question.

Comment: @GPhilip: Well, I've added a few more details comparing the two presentations (Schrijver's and Deming's), which I think sheds more light, but I can't say I can fully understand what Deming defines there, other that it's probably an equivalent notion of M-posy (somehow).

Comment: Thank you, let me try to understand your additions.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong here, but one way to make sense of this... I think the blossom pair is literally just referring to the two blossoms in question(the ones in which $v_1$ and $v_{2k}$ are blossom tips), and NOT the path in between, so your edges $x_1x_2$ and $y_1y_2$ are not in the blossom pair because they are in the path, not the blossoms.

Comment: But then see the picture I added to the question now: There is again no way to reach y2 from x1 via an alternating path which starts and ends with light edges ... .

Comment: You probably also want $x_1x_2$ and $y_1y_2$ to be in different blossoms of the blossom pair. I am not familiar with this claim myself, so I am not sure. If I have time(unless you provide another immediate counterexample), I will try to prove it given this extra condition. It does seem that the claim is written poorly though.(which will happen if one is so familiar with the work they're writing up that they forget to include the little points)

Comment: If the edges are in different blossoms, then I think I also see why the claim holds. Sadly, the author has stated his claim without this condition: the two heavy edges just have to belong to a blossom pair as per his claim. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. This would be a great opportunity for you to E-mail this author and point out his mistake(assuming he is still around). Also, being able to give him a proof that it works under these new conditions we suggested would be nice.

Comment: Deming probably does mean they must be in different blossoms. This is because of Deming's theorem 2. "An arbitrary graph G is K-E iff for any maximum matching M, the extension G’ contains no pair of biconnected heavy edges." This is translated in Schrijver as theorem 30.13 "G has the Koenig property iff for each maximum-size matching M there is no M-flower and no M-posy", where M-flower was defined as the one-sided version of the M-possy: http://imgur.com/TgyftyV. If you extend that M-flower as in Deming's extension construction you get a M-possy.

Comment: (cont'd) because $v_0$ gets duplicated in the extension and you a "triangle" for it. So what Deming's theorem 2 is [equivalently] saying is that G' (the extension of G) contains no M-posy; this is enough to entail that G contains no M-posy nor M-flower.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use the claim about biconnected pairs of heavy edges to clarify
what must be included in the "blossom pair."
But it seems problematic!

[image]

In this picture, $x_1 x_2$ and $y_1 y_2$ are a biconnected pair of heavy edges (right?).
Yet, they are contained in no blossom pair.
The only blossoms are:

- $a,x_1,x_2,a$
- $b_,x_1,x_2,b$
- $x_1, a, b, x_1$, and
- $x_2, a, b, x_2$.

Any alternating path, starting and ending with heavy edges, between any of these blossom tips, does not involve $y_1 y_2$. Hence that edge is not involved in any blossom pair in this graph, for any of the potential definitions.

So, I believe the claims as stated are wrong. However, what the author wants to use is this:

> A graph contains a biconnected pair of heavy edges if and only if it
>   also contains a blossom pair.

I believe that this is true, despite the erroneous statements attempting to prove it.

In particular, in the claim in the question, what the author actually requires is:

> Let $G$ be a graph with a perfect matching $M$, and $B$ be a blossom pair with respect to the matching $M$.
>   Then there exist a pair of heavy edges $x_1x_2$ and $y_1y_2$ belonging to $B$
>   such that for each $i,j=1,2$, there is an alternating path $p(x_i,y_j)$ beginning
>   and ending with light edges and contained in $B$.

Comment: Thank you. What would be part of a blossom pair for the highlighted statements in your answer to hold? Just the path? Just the blossoms? Both the blossoms and the path? What is the definition of a blossom pair which you have in mind?

Comment: I think he must mean it consists of the path and both blossoms. Since we will, in general, have the edges $x_1 x_2$ and $y_1 y_2$ in the two different blossoms, and the alternating path will need to cross the path, while remaining in $B$.

Comment: Indeed there are four paths here as required: $x_1bay_1$, $x_1aby_2$, $x_2bay_1$, $x_2aby_2$. But there is no blossom containing $y_1y_2$.

Comment: If you add another square to the other side of $x_1x_2$ you can get a pair of biconnected heavy edges neither of which belongs to an M-posy. The issue is that biconnected heavy edges can (one or both) belong to even-length cycles in the matching. However in order for two of them to be biconnected their paths must pass through an M-posy, which allows the number of required paths to go from 2 to 4.